# Multi_index query with new CDT

Tags: multi-index, eosio.cdt

Because name is no longer a `uint64_t` type I created my struct like this:

```
struct [[eosio::table]] game
{
    uint64_t id; //auto increment
    name host;
    name guest= name("none");
    name player_to_play =name("none");
    name winner = name("none");
    string2dvector game_state;
    string game_name;
    uint64_t primary_key() const { return id; }
    uint64_t by_host() const { return host.value; }
    EOSLIB_SERIALIZE(game, (id)(host)(guest)(player_to_play)(winner)(game_state)(game_name))

};

// table definition
typedef eosio::multi_index<"game"_n, game, 
indexed_by<"host"_n, const_mem_fun<game, uint64_t, &game::by_host>>
> games;
```

Then I try to get the table indexed by secondary key like this:

```
auto host_games = existing_games.get_index<"host"_n>();
```

but when I try to compile I get the following error:

> error: no matching member function for call to 'find'
>           auto iterator = host_games.find(host);
>
> /usr/local/eosio.cdt/bin/../include/eosiolib/multi_index.hpp:429:28: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'const eosio::name' to 'eosio::multi_index<7035924439720001536, tablegame::game, eosio::indexed_by<7868228353667366912, eosio::const_mem_fun > >::index<7868228353667366912, eosio::const_mem_fun, 0, false>::secondary_key_type' (aka 'unsigned long long') for 1st argument
>               const_iterator find( secondary_key_type&& secondary )const {

I tried to change the host type to `uint64_t` and `return host;` from by_host() or try `auto host_games = existing_games.get_index<"host.value"_n>();` but didn't work.

Any thoughts?

P.S the new CDT is a pain in the ass. I should not have updated :P.

Answer (score 2):

You can call `name.value` to get a `uin64_t` representation of the name.  In your `find` call, you want to do `auto iterator = host_games.find(host.value);` to match the `uint64_t` type that your secondary index is returning.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The problem was in creating the `get_index<T>()`  I managed to solve it thanks to the developers group in telegram once again.

Comment: Changing to name.value helped me with the
error: no viable conversion from 'eosio::name' to 'uint64_t' (aka 'unsigned long long')

Answer (score 2):

To anyone having the same issues. I managed to fix it like this:

```
struct [[eosio::table]] game
{
    uint64_t id; //auto increment
    name host;
    name guest= name("none");
    name player_to_play =name("none");
    name winner = name("none");
    string2dvector game_state;
    string game_name;
    uint64_t primary_key() const { return id; }
    uint64_t get_host() const { return host.value; }
    EOSLIB_SERIALIZE(game, (id)(host)(guest)(player_to_play)(winner)(game_state)(game_name))

};
// table definition
typedef eosio::multi_index<"game"_n, game, 
indexed_by<"byhost"_n, const_mem_fun<game, uint64_t, &game::get_host>>
> games;
```

and

```
games existing_games(_self, _self.value);
auto host_games = existing_games.get_index<"byhost"_n>();
auto iterator = host_games.find(host.value);
```

Thanks for your time